# PyAutogui : How stop Loop When an image Appears?

Tags: python, bots, pyautogui

during my while loop I want as soon as it detects an image it stops but it does not work (I use pyautogui), give an opinion on the code please :

```
# Combat
nike = None
tour = "tour.png"
win = "win.png"
sort = "sort.png"
end = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(win)

while (nike == None):
    try:
     nike = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(tour)
     pyautogui.press("b")
     attack = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("attack.png",confidence=0.7)
     pyautogui.moveTo(attack)
     pyautogui.click()
     pyautogui.press("b")
     attack = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("attack.png",confidence=0.7)
     pyautogui.moveTo(attack)
     pyautogui.click()
     pyautogui.press("f1")
     end = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(win)
     if (end == True):
      pyautogui.press("enter")
     break
```

Answer (score 1):

**The problem is that `pyautogui.locateOnScreen()` doesn't return `True`/`False`**

`pyautogui.locateOnScreen()` returns either the coordinates of that image or `None` if the image is not found.

So, you would have to change `if (end == True):` to `if (end != None):`.

Leaving your final code as this:

```
# Combat
nike = None
tour = "tour.png"
win = "win.png"
sort = "sort.png"
end = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(win)

while (nike == None):
    try:
     nike = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(tour)
     pyautogui.press("b")
     attack = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("attack.png",confidence=0.7)
     pyautogui.moveTo(attack)
     pyautogui.click()
     pyautogui.press("b")
     attack = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("attack.png",confidence=0.7)
     pyautogui.moveTo(attack)
     pyautogui.click()
     pyautogui.press("f1")
     end = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(win)
     if (end != None):
      pyautogui.press("enter")
     break
```

Also, in Python, you do not need parentheses in `if` and `while` statements. So you could change `if (end != None):` to `if end != None:`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did what you told me but it gave me this:
  ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

What should I do?